# create local file in C drive (electron)

Tags: node.js, electron

I tried to create a local json in C drive but after I run the code, I didn't see the file. Can I use file-system to do this?

```
public createSeaReport(): any {
  return fs.mkdir('/src/assets/json', () => {
    if (!fs.existsSync('/src/assets/json/sea_report.json')) {
      console.log('file create');
      fs.writeFile('/src/assets/json/sea_report.json', '{"sea_report": []}', error => console.log(error));
    }
});
}
```

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\src\assets\json\sea_report.json'

Comment: Try adding error handling to the callback on `fs.writeFile`, if there's an error, it would be good to know what it is

Comment: I had add in the error handling. and update my code. I still can't see the file in my C drive.

Comment: Do you get anything logged to the console?

Comment: I haven't developed on Windows in ages, but aren't the paths supposed to point to `C:\ ` instead of `/`?

Comment: just an error message that I show above

Comment: I have this error in mkdir: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\....'

Comment: I try to run as administrator and it work. Is there any way that I can force user to run the app as administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This is likely due to your account access rights on windows. You can double check if you are able to create files in C:\ using the file explorer.

For me (Standard Account - Non-Admin) - I can create folders under C:\ but I can not create files:

```
fs.writeFile('C:\\test.json'); //does not work for me - EPERM
fs.mkdir('C:\\test'); //works for me
```

Your code should work when you execute it in an admin shell (Right Click->Run as Administrator).

---

Can you try:

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile('C:\\Users\\MyAccount\\Downloads\\test.json');
```

Comment: I have this error in mkdir: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\....'